# Two 2D Arrays, Two Matrices, One File

Tags: c++, file-io, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to figure out how to read two matrices from one file and then assign them to two different 2D arrays. The matrices are separated by a new line in the text file. I managed to get the first one to read successfully but now I cant figure out how to read the second one. The way I see it, the the line that separates the two matrices must be considered and checked for. How do I get the program to read and assign the second matrix to an array?

Both matrices and arrays are 4x4.

This is what the text file looks like:

```
3  4  5  7

5 16  7 12

11 12  3  9

9  8  1 12   


15  4  3  6

1 12  3 12

7  8 19  9

11 12  8  5
```

Here is my code for the first array which works fine.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y )
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x )
    {
        infile >> array1[x][y]; 
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the array I can't figure out.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y )
      {
          for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x )
          {
              if(x == '\n' && y == '\n') //My attempt. 
              {
                   infile >> array2[x][y]; 
              }  
          }
      }
```

Here is the output:

```
This will check to make sure numbers in file are written to the first array.
3 4 5 7
5 16 7 12
11 12 3 9
9 8 1 12

This will check to make sure numbers in file are written to the second array.
9.21742e-314 1.0572e-307 7.29112e-304 3.87184e-306
1.06498e-307 1.65425e-317 6.79039e-313 4.22748e+266
5.92879e-323 1.06196e-307 6.95089e-308 9.88799e-315
1.79648e-313 8.48798e-314 6.95224e-308 1.06193e-307
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To read the matrices, search StackOverflow for "C++ read file parse matrix"

Comment: For a Matrix class, search the web for "C++ FAQ Matrix".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are reading your file using the "formatted input" operator `>>`, the kind and amount whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) between the items (numbers in your case) is insignificant. This means you do not get to see the empty line at all. If you need to parse a file based on its lines, consider using `getline` instead and parsing the single lines using a `istringstream`.

If on the other hand you know the size of both arrays, you can simply read the second array just as you read the first array. The extra empty line just gets ignored.

The reason your code for reading the second array does not work is that you compare the index variables to `'\n'`, which happens to be 10 on most systems. As your index ranges from 0 to 3, the `if` condition is never true, so nothing gets read at all, so you are seeing a dump of uninitialized memory.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I can't believe the fix was that easy. Thank you for clearing things up and answering my noob question :P

Answer (score 0):

You can read the second array exactly as you read the first. The reason is that, when you start reading from a stream, at first it discards whitespaces till it encounters something that is not whitespace. Then it gets the numbers/character one by one till it encounters whitespace again. So, there is no problem with the newline and you can read the remaining array without problems.